# Удалить файлы, загруженные в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, файлы, ресурсы

Есть 3 формы. Каждая по очереди открывается, происходят определенные операции (скачивание изображений, затем их конвертация и вставка в поля webbrowser). По завершению этих операций 2 и 3 формы закрываются. Остается открыта 1 форма, т.е. главная, на которой происходит первоначальное скачивание этих файлов с помощью WebClient.

И вот при попытке удалить эти файлы (формы 2 и 3 уже закрыты), у меня ничего не получается. Они как были на диске, так и остаются. Только после закрытия программы они исчезают.

Скачивание делаю так:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(poster), disk.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName("poster" + pathExtString));
webClient.Dispose();
```

Вставляю изображения в webbrowser так:

```
Populate().ContinueWith((_) => {}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

async Task PopulateInputFile_poster(HtmlElement file_poster)
{
    file_poster.Focus();

    // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
    var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(
        (_) =>
            {
            // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
            SendKeys.Send(disk + "" + "poster.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
            }, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );

    file_poster.InvokeMember("Click"); // this shows up the dialog
    await sendKeyTask;

    // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
    await Task.Delay(500);
}


foreach (HtmlElement file_poster in elements)
{
    if (file_poster.GetAttribute("name") == "screen")
    {
        file_poster.Focus();
        await PopulateInputFile_poster(file_poster);
    }
}
```

Так вот, если не открывать эту третью форму, где вставляются изображения в webbrowser, то все хорошо и файлы удаляются. Но если открыть, то уже ничего не выйдет даже после закрытия самой третьей формы.

Удаляю так:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(disk.Text+"poster.jpg");
```

P.S. Вторая форма открывается не всегда, поэтому по ней вопросов точно быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно `WebBrowser` сохраняет ссылку на файл. В этом случае можно попробовать перейти на другую страницу и удалить после перехода:

```
void DeleteFile()
{    
    needToDeleteFile = true;
    //переходим на пустую страницу
    webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
}

//обрабатываем событие перехода на страницу и затем удаляем файлы
void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (needToDeleteFile)
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
        needToDeleteFile = false;
    }
}
```

Код взял из ответа на похожий вопрос на английском: [How can i delete the file that has been navigated in a webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495619/how-can-i-delete-the-file-that-has-been-navigated-in-a-webbrowser-control)

В качестве альтернативы можно попробовать явно освободить все ресурсы `WebBrowser`:

```
webBrowser.Dispose();
//попробовать удалить файлы после этого
```

Comment: Попробовал при закрытии формы явно освободиться ресурсы. В итоге после закрытия формы и нажатия на копку, отвечающую за удаление файлов, ничего не произошло. Но стоило закрыть программу, как файл тут же исчез...